# Out of what type of cargo plane and at what altitude would the MC jump?

Tags: transportation, travel, aircraft, altitude

The main character needs to get from England to Norway, fast, and without anyone (Beyond a smuggler) finding out.

He’ll be jumping out of a cargo plane that is flying from England to Norway in the middle of the night. (Book related)

-What type of cargo planes usually fly these routes that are suitable for the MC to jump out of?

-And at what altitude would these planes usually fly?  (He’ll have all the equipment he needs for a HALO jump if needs be)

Comment: Seems off-topic to me - there doesn't seem to be any world building, it's just asking to cross-reference the *list of cargo planes in use between England and Norway* and the *list of cargo planes that can be used for parachuting*.

Comment: A cargo plane on a regular route from England to Norway is going to be an airliner, traveling at airliner speeds and altitudes (say, 15000 feet). Cargo holds aren't usually heated or pressurized, and they aren't designed to be opened in flight (quite the contrary, multiple safety features are designed to *prevent* this). This doesn't seem to be an especially practical method to me.

Comment: A better option might be a small water plane that lands in one of Norway's narrow fjords, shielded from radar. A smuggler or night fisher could witness this.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

The cargo planes in question are mostly the [cargo versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-8#747-8_Freighter) of regular airliners. They are not designed to open doors in flight. While civilian-operated versions of military transport aircraft exist, they are not optimized for cost-effective civilian transport. They will cruise around 40k feet.

Options for your story:

- The character hides in the [wheel well](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-60104010) of an airliner, with warm clothing and an oxygen supply. Exciting scenes as he sneaks in and out.
- The character bribes some [offshore helicopter operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristow_Helicopters) to hitch flights from station to station, labeled as 'supercargo' or 'just an employee who needs to go somewhere.' Exciting scenes as the cover is almost blown on some oil rig in the North Sea.
- The character takes a ferry to North Ireland, crosses the border, takes a [ferry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittany_Ferries) from the Republic of Ireland to France or Spain, and then tries to avoid spot checks on any of the Schengen land borders. (Looking European helps ...)